How can I create a keybind that opens an R dataframe to view in VS Code
I have recently transitioned from RStudio to VS Code, in RStudio, ctrl + right click runs the view() command in R on the variable you click on (for example a dataframe) and it opens it in a separate viewer.
I want to do the same thing in VS Code, but i cant get it to work no matter what extension or approach I use, I have gotten it to work on file names, but if i use it on a dataframe, it points me to the line where that dataframe was defined instead of opening it to view.
Any ideas would be appreciated, since this is a very important keybind for me.

Did you try writing your own macro with autohotkey? Admittedly I don't use R in VSCode, but im fairly certain that there must be a way with autohotkey.

I tried witting a macro, using the multi-command extension, but it didn't work and as I don't have much experience with macros and the language vscode uses, I'm not sure whats wrong with it or how to fix it
